# Calculate probability of a team ranking inside a league

Tags: python, probability

the goal of this project is to calculate the probability of each making the top 6(the remaining scenarios where each team win or loses the remaining matches but still make it to the top 6) so I made a 3D list to input the match history(the matches that are played and we know the results) the problem is I don't know how to calculate the probability of the team rank because it also depends on other teams I wanna find a formula or a code to solve it

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, name, pos):
       self.name = name
       self.pos = pos
       self.w = 0
       self.l = 0
       self.score = ""

    def upd_score(self, history):
        # check the rows
        for match in history[self.pos]:
            if match == ["w"]:
                self.w += 1
            elif match == ["l"]:
                self.l += 1
        # check the columns
        for match in history:
            if match[self.pos] == ["l"]:
                self.w += 1
            elif match[self.pos] == ["w"]:
                self.l += 1
        self.score = f"{self.w} - {self.l}"

    def get_score(self):
        print(f"the score is {self.score} ")

RGE = Team("RGE", 1)
VIT = Team("VIT", 2)
G2 = Team("G2", 3)
MSF = Team("MSF", 4)
AST = Team("AST", 5)
MAD = Team("MAD", 6)
FNC = Team("FNC", 7)
SK = Team("SK", 8)
XL = Team("XL", 9)
BDS = Team("BDS", 10)


MATCH_HISTORY = [
    [["X"], [RGE], [VIT], [G2], [MSF], [AST], [MAD], [FNC], [SK], [XL], [BDS]],
    [[RGE], ["X"], ["w"], ["w"], ["l"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[VIT], ["w"], ["X"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[G2], ["w"], [""], ["X"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[MSF], ["w"], [""], [""], ["X"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[AST], ["l"], [""], [""], [""], ["X"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[MAD], ["w"], [""], [""], [""], [""], ["X"], [""], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[FNC], ["l"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], ["X"], [""], [""], [""]],
    [[SK], ["w"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], ["X"], [""], [""]],
    [[XL], ["w"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], ["X"], [""]],
    [[BDS], ["w"], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], [""], ["X"]],
]

# SCORE UPDATING
RGE.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
VIT.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
G2.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
MSF.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
AST.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
MAD.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
FNC.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
SK.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
XL.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
BDS.upd_score(MATCH_HISTORY)
```

to calculate the score: if the team is in the rows win I'll put "w" and if the team is in the columns I'll put "l" and "X" for cases that can't be filled(a team cannot play against itself)

btw I am still a beginner so please if there is a way to optimize my code tell me and if you suggest me something it will be nice if explain it or link me something that can help

Comment: What do you mean by "probability of making the top 6"? Can't you just print a standings based on the w-l percentage?

Comment: the question is not clear.

Comment: sorry i hope it's more clear now

Comment: hey! just to be sure about it, the match history is read vit won vs rge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loved the idea and couldn't resist doing it, so here is the code

Basically it iterates over all the possibilities that exist for all the matches that have not been done yet, and calculate the stats of each team beeing in the top N (that you can change in the code)

Only problem is that the number of possibilities is 2^undone_matches and it goes high really quickly, so you can't run the program for more than 15 undone matches...

An other possibility would be to do it not recursivly but mathematicaly with probabilities, but I'm too lazy for it xD

PS: right now the program do not handle equalities in score and take the 1st team with the same score, I let you take care of it if you want :)

```
import copy

class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.w = 0
       self.l = 0

    def init_scores(self, MH):
        for rowIndex in range(0, len(MH[0])):
            if MH[rowIndex][0] == self.name:
                index = rowIndex
        for columnIndex in range(0, len(MH[0])):
            result = MH[columnIndex][index]
            if result == "w":
                self.l += 1
            elif result == "l":
                self.w += 1
                
        for columnIndex in range(0, len(MH[0])):
            if MH[0][columnIndex] == self.name:
                index = columnIndex
        for rowIndex in range(0, len(MH[0])):
            result = MH[index][rowIndex]
            if result == "w":
                self.w += 1
            elif result == "l":
                self.l += 1
    
            
    def toString(self):
        r  = "| " + self.name.ljust(9) + "|\n"
        r += "|" + "----------" + "|\n"
        r += "| w: " + str(self.w).ljust(6) + "|\n"
        r += "| l: " + str(self.l).ljust(6) + "|\n"
        return r
    
    def getScore(self):
        return [self.name, self.w]
        
        
def createAllPossibilities(MH, topN, results):
    coo = emptyCellExist(MH)
    if coo[0] >= 0:
        cp1 = copy.deepcopy(MH)
        cp1[coo[0]][coo[1]] = "w"
        createAllPossibilities(cp1, topN, results)
        cp2 = copy.deepcopy(MH)
        cp2[coo[0]][coo[1]] = "l"
        createAllPossibilities(cp2, topN, results)
    else:
        Teams = []
        Teams.append(Team("RGE"))
        Teams.append(Team("VIT"))
        Teams.append(Team("G2"))
        Teams.append(Team("MSF"))
        Teams.append(Team("AST"))
        Teams.append(Team("MAD"))
        Teams.append(Team("FNC"))
        Teams.append(Team("SK"))
        Teams.append(Team("XL"))
        Teams.append(Team("BDS"))
        
        for t in Teams:
            t.init_scores(MH)
            
        scores = []
        for t in Teams:
            scores.append(t.getScore())
        
        for n in range(topN):
            best = 0
            index = -1
            for t in range(len(scores)):
                if best < scores[t][1]:
                    best = scores[t][1]
                    index = t
            scores[index][1] = 0
            #print(scores)
            results[index] += 1
            

def emptyCellExist(MH):
    for row in range(len(MH[0])):
        for cell in range(len(MH[0])):
            if MH[row][cell] == "":
                return [row, cell]
    return [-1, -1]



# current score
MATCH_HISTORY = [   ["X",   "RGE", "VIT", "G2", "MSF", "AST", "MAD", "FNC", "SK", "XL", "BDS"],
                    ["RGE", "X",   "w",   "w",  "l",   "l",   "w",   "l",   "l",  "w",  ""],
                    ["VIT", "w",   "X",   "l",  "w",   "l",   "w",   "l",   "w",  "w",  ""],
                    ["G2",  "w",   "l",   "X",  "w",   "w",   "l",   "l",   "w",  "w",  ""],
                    ["MSF", "w",   "l",   "v",  "X",   "w",   "w",   "l",   "w",  "w",  ""],
                    ["AST", "l",   "l",   "l",  "l",   "X",   "l",   "l",   "l",  "",  ""],
                    ["MAD", "w",   "l",   "v",  "w",   "l",   "X",   "l",   "l",  "",  ""],
                    ["FNC", "l",   "l",   "l",  "w",   "l",   "l",   "X",   "w",  "",  ""],
                    ["SK",  "w",   "l",   "w",  "l",   "w",   "w",   "l",   "X",  "",  ""],
                    ["XL",  "w",   "l",   "w",  "w",   "l",   "l",   "w",   "w",  "X",  ""],
                    ["BDS", "w",   "l",   "w",  "w",   "l",   "w",   "w",   "l",  "",  "X"]]

# top teams must be top X
topN = 6

# count the number of matches done and left to do
matchesDone = 0
matchesLeft = 0
for row in MATCH_HISTORY:
    for cell in row:
        if cell == "w" or cell == "l":
            matchesDone += 1
        elif cell == "":
            matchesLeft += 1
print("matches done : " + str(matchesDone))
print("matches left to do : " + str(matchesLeft))
print("that's " + str(pow(2, matchesLeft)) + " possibilities\n")

if matchesLeft > 20:
    print("that's way to much for me")
else:
    # if the number of matches left to do is low enought, then start calculating the probabilities
    results = [0 for a in range(len(MATCH_HISTORY[0]))]
    createAllPossibilities(MATCH_HISTORY, topN, results)
    
    print(MATCH_HISTORY[0][1:])
    for a in range(len(results)):
        results[a] /= (pow(2, matchesLeft)*topN)
        results[a] = int(results[a]*1000)/10
    print(results)
    

while 1:
    pass
```

Comment: results[a] /= (pow(2, matchesLeft)*topN)    can you explain why you multiplied it by topN @ren

Answer (score 0):

For a rudimentary probability of a team winning, you could use their wins over their total losses.
`self.w / (self.w + self.l)`
To calculate a (again very rudimentary) probability for team rankings, just work out the probabilities of all the teams and order them from highest to lowest. e.g.

```
# teams is an array containing instances of your teams
team_win_probs = []

for team in teams:
    team_win_probs.append((team.name, team.w / (team.w + team.l)))

team_win_probs.sort(key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True) # the lambda gets the second elements of the tuple
```

Here I've used a tuple to couple the team name and the team win probability, and used a lambda in `list`'s sort parameter `key` to get the probability out of the `tuple` and sort based on it.

I hope this has helped :)